# Installing ROS on AWS EC2 Instance with Ubuntu Desktop GUI

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have an installation procedure for ROS onto an AWS EC2 instance that utilizes the standard Ubuntu Desktop GUI? I have found several  discussions online about using a VNC solution, but in talking to AWS, they are saying that any of these solutions of using a GUI will slow the system down significantly. I don't understand why the GUI is different and slower than a Window s Server GUI accessed through RDP.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208098/installing-ros-on-aws-ec2-instance-with-ubuntu-desktop-gui/) by [cmackin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22119/cmackin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install GUI on EC2 linux instances and use VNC to connect to it from a variety of devices.
see this link for setting it up on Ubuntu.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server

---

Originally posted by [mwkorver](https://answers.ros.org/users/23048/mwkorver/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Typically AWS is accessed and configured via ssh. I have installed ROS on an AWS instance, but only on the command line. If you want to use windowed functions of ROS you would have to setup an X window server on your instance and use that to visualize any windows on your host PC.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1